# How do I select the first 8 characters after a hyphen in a string?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a postgres SQL server where in a table I have a column where the values look like this:

[image]

I want to write a query that would output only the first 8 characters after the hyphen, which is simply the date without hyphens. The output I want would be in the form of "20181206", but would also love to know how to re-format this into the hyphenated format!

Answer (score 3):

With a combination of `position` and `substring` functions.

```
substring(val,position('-' in val)+1,8)
```

To reformat in the hyphenated format, use `to_char`, after `cast`ing the substring to `date`.(The assumption is that the substring is a valid date)

```
to_char(substring(val,position('-' in val)+1,8)::date,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Answer (score 1):

With regular expression:

```
select regexp_replace(val, '.*-(....)(..)(..).*', '\1-\2-\3') from 
  (select '2342-20181206000000' AS val) x;
+----------------+
| regexp_replace |
+----------------+
| 2018-12-06     |
+----------------+
(1 row)
```

Comment: This could have a side effect if ever number had a second dash `2342-20181206000000-2` as .* is greedy ;) `.*?-(....)(..)(..)` could be safer.

Comment: Totally correct. Lots of ways to improve this, especially stopping the greediness with a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select substring(colname from (strpos(colname, '-')+1) for 8)  from Table1 ;
```

check:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9bab3/3/0

Answer (score 0):

Would<strike>n't necessarily</strike> call it more beautiful,<strike>but</strike> and it works:

```sql
select (regexp_match('2342-20181206000000', '^\d+-(\d{8})'))[1]::date as "Date";
```